# Search and Fetch string values in comma separated string which match the post variable from URL PHP MySql

Tags: mysql

Hi i have a sql table like this

```
id     fname     cat                              address        status

1      Bash      Wedding venue                      ABC            a
2      Ashu      Wedding venue, Wedding card        BCD            a
3      jash      Wedding venue                      ABC            a
4      hash      Wedding venue                      BCD            a   
5      Rash      Wedding card                       BCD            a
```

Id "2" has 2 cat values. What i want is to fetch id "2" in both cases whether post variable in URL is "Wedding venue" or "Wedding cat". In detail if URL is something like

```
www.example.com/list.php?cat=Wedding venue
```

Output:

```
id     fname     cat                              address        status

1      Bash      Wedding venue                      ABC            a
2      Ashu      Wedding venue, Wedding card        BCD            a
3      jash      Wedding venue                      ABC            a
4      hash      Wedding venue                      BCD            a
```

And for URL

```
www.example.com/list.php?cat=Wedding card
```

Output:

```
id     fname     cat                              address        status

2      Ashu      Wedding venue, Wedding card        BCD            a
5      Rash      Wedding card                       BCD            a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LIKE CONCAT():

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE cat LIKE CONCAT('%Wedding venue%')
```

EDIT:

It will also work without concat:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE cat LIKE '%Wedding venue%'
```

but for cross SQL compatibility (if you wish to switch to another sql version tomorrow without changing code) I recommend to use concat, as some other sqls do not compare strings if request made in different encoding than table, and single value concat is a workaround there.

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept answer by clicking checkbox on the left. Cheers.

Comment: Why using `CONCAT` here? You aren't concatenate multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Hi we can use like operator in a query to fetch such type of string matching.

**LIKE '%Wedding card%' "**

```
$searchvalue='';

if(isset($_REQUEST['cat']))
    {
    $searchvalue=$_REQUEST['cat'];
    }
else{
    $searchvalue='';
    }

SELECT * FROM `address` where cat like '%$searchvalue%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` clause. For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE cat LIKE '%$_GET['cat']%'
```

It works for me.

Comment: Never recommend to $_GET[] value from user directly in SQL as you can get SQL injection.